# Parse a text file using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to parse a text file using regex. I am using notepad++ and would like to search for the keyword **Answer** and delete everything after it within the same line including the keyword. Here is an example of the text file:

```
Give me the links for some blogs related to SQL Server.

A. www.sqlskills.com
B. www.techcunrch.com
C. www.nbc.com
D. www.forbes.com

Answer: A
```

I would like to generate a regex for it and replace all answers with blanks so that I have only questions which I can administer to somebody. Is that possible?

For the above case the result should be:

```
Give me the links for some blogs related to SQL Server.

A. www.sqlskills.com
B. www.techcunrch.com
C. www.nbc.com
D. www.forbes.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the answer is a capital letter add Notepad++ will *multiline* search.

```
\s+Answer:\s+[A-Z]
```

Comment: Thanks works!..I just realized may be I could have done Answer.* or Answer.+ too!

Comment: When it comes to regular expressions, remember they are greedy. Therefore it is best to be as specific as possible.